# Using your slope intercept form equation, find the amount of donations needed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You need to create a valentines package. 50 valentine packages cost $4300. You've started your own charity donation program. The three scenarios listed below show how much donations(y) you've collected in(x) days.

Items are price times 50.

So,

Flowers: $20 * 50 = 1000

Candy: $20 * 50 = $1000

Card: $12 * 50 = $600

Gift: $18 * 50 = $900

Dinner: $16 * 50 = $800

Total Expense for 50 valentines packages = $4300

Given three ordered pairs:

Scenario 1: (6, 305); 6 days, you've collected $305.00

Scenario 2: (14, 585); 14 days, you've collected $585.00

Scenario 3: (0, 125); at the start of the donation program, you had $125.00 saved up

Based on the three scenarios, write the equation in slope intercept form.

Using the amount of money you need to create 50 valentine packages, how many donations do you need?

I found the slope using points (0, 125) since this is when the donation program started and (14, 585) since this the two week period from when donations started. I arrived at y=230/7x + 125. Now, using this, if I solve for y = 4300, this just gives me the days it would take to earn $4300 in donations.

Comment: The input data does not seem correct.

Comment: Can you point out where it seems off?

Comment: If you find the slope using scenario $1$ and $3$, scenario $2$ does not fit that line. Scenario $2$ should have been $545$ instead of $585$ for that OR the question should clarify further. Also, there is no info given that you can use to find _how_  _many_ donations? How much, yes!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will bring this to the attention of my kid's instructor. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Money obtained (y) :
$y = 280/8 x + 125$ where x is the number of days and you solve for y = 4300

Comment: I assume you found the slope from scenario 1 & 2, but what about scenario 3? Aren't you supposed to find the slope from start(0, 125) to end(14, 585)?

Comment: Also, once you solve for y = 4300, then x tells you how many days it would take to reach $4300. How does this tell us how many donations we need?